# SQL: adding each row cell in one column of table 2 to different column cells on the same row in table 1

Tags: sql

I have two tables (table1 and table2) and I would like to have the end result as depicted
[image: here]

Does anyone know how to get this result in SQL syntax?

table 1 syntax
    SELECT actID, date
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY actID
    ;

table 2 syntax
    SELECT act, timestamp, time
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY act, timestamp
    ;

endResult syntax:
??

Comment: you are looking for PIVOT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Use CROSS APPLY

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would often approach this using aggregation:

```
select t1.actid, t1.timestamp,
       max(case when t2.timestamp = 5 then t2.time end) as time_5,
       max(case when t2.timestamp = 7 then t2.time end) as time_7,
       max(case when t2.timestamp = 8 then t2.time end) as time_8,
       max(case when t2.timestamp = 10 then t2.time end) as time_10
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.actid = t2.act
group by t1.actid, t1.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to join to table 2 four different times, as follows:

```
Select 
    t1.actID
    , t1.date
    , t25.time as t5
    , t27.time as t7
    , t28.time as t8
    , t210.time as t10
From table1 as t1
    left outer join table2 as t25
        on t25.act = t1.actid
        and t25.timestamp = 5
    left outer join table2 as t27
        on t27.act = t1.actid
        and t27.timestamp = 7
    left outer join table2 as t28
        on t28.act = t1.actid
        and t28.timestamp = 8
    left outer join table2 as t210
        on t210.act = t1.actid
        and t210.timestamp = 10
```

Make sense?